# terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-list

I am trying to query the user for first a number of inputs, then fill a dynamic list with that number of inputs. Then print them in reverse order. For some reason I get the SIGSEGV error, but I cannot find any infinite loops or address error. Help me find what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int input;
    printf("Enter a non-negative number: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    int *listA;
    listA = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int[input]));
    printf("Now, enter %d non-negative numbers: ", input);
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        scanf("%d", listA[i]);
    }
    printf("In reverse order, your input is: ");
    for (int i = input-1; i >=0; i-- ) {
        printf("%d",listA[i]);
    }
    free(listA);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try compiling your code with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` with `gcc`).  Your line:

```
scanf("%d", listA[i]);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%d", &listA[i]);
```